# Counting sub-strings count

Tags: python, dictionary, count, substring

Suppose I have a string `aaa` and I want the count of all the substrings in this `aaa`.
I do that by the following code:

If I use the following code:

```
s="aaa"   
res = [s[i: j] for i in range(len(s))for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
d={}
for i in res:
    if i not in d.keys():
        d[i]=s.count(i)
print(d)
```

I get the output:

```
{'a': 3, 'aa': 1, 'aaa': 1}
```

But according to my need, I want the count of `aa` to be two as in one chance I can pick the `aa` from two positions i.e. `aa` from `s[0:2]` and other from `s[2:4]`.

If I modify my code like below I get the desired result for `aa` but the count of `a` is wrong now.

```
s="aaa"
res = [s[i: j] for i in range(len(s))for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
d={}
for i in res:
    if i not in d.keys():
        d[i]=0
        for j in range(len(s)+1):
            d[i]+=s[:j].count(i)
print(d)
```

I get the following output which is wrong:

```
{'a': 6, 'aa': 2, 'aaa': 1}
```

Can anybody help me to get the desired output?

Desired Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'aa': 2, 'aaa': 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
s = "aaa"
res = [s[i: j] for i in range(len(s))for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
d = {}
for i in res:
     if i not in d.keys():
             d[i] = 1
     else:
             d[i] += 1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this via `re`.

```
x="aaa"
import re
keys=["a", "aa", "aaa"]
for key in keys:
    print re.findall(r"(?=({}))".format(key), x)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a']
['aa', 'aa']
['aaa']
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspiration [all sub strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-all-substrings-of-given-string/)

**solution**

```
test_str = "aaa"
ssc = {}
for ss in [test_str[i: j] for i in range(len(test_str)) for j in range(i + 1, len(test_str) + 1)]:
    ssc[ss] = 1 if ss not in ssc.keys() else ssc[ss] + 1
ssc
```

**output**

```
{'a': 3, 'aa': 2, 'aaa': 1}
```